# Converting user input from prompts in javascript into an array and then pushing it onto an object

Tags: javascript

I want to take the user's input in the form of a prompt and convert it into an array so I can push it onto a previously created object

Here is my code(script):

```
     var addperson = prompt("Would you like to add someone yes or no?( you must type 'yes' in this exact way)")
        if(addperson == "yes" ){
                var firstName = prompt("What is this person's first name?");
                var lastName = prompt("What is this person's last name?");
                var age = prompt("How old is this person?");
                var email = prompt("What is their email adress?");

                    if(!/^[@]+$/.test(email) || !email){
                    alert("Your email is valid");
                    }else{

                        alert("You did not give a valid email please re-type it, and make sure you include the @ symbol");
                        email;
                    }


            function newPeople(){
                var newPerson = [ firstName, lastName, age, email ];

                var something = [];
                for(var i=0; i<newPerson.length; i++){
                    var data2 = newPerson[i].split(';');
                        var lines2 = [];
                        for(var j=0; j<data2.length; j++){
                            lines2.push(data2[j]);
                        }
                        something.push(lines2);

                }
            something.push(lines);  
            }       
        }  
    console.log(lines);
```

Comment: Please format and indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly push a new object into the array using .push .
Check this [working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/rugeoLxj/).

The object that is added is then printed onto the console in this format :

```
Age: "234"
Email: "d@d."
FirstName: "jh"
LastName: "j"
```

Comment: I know that I am trying to take a user input and convert it to an array.

Comment: how do you want to store the user input into the object , as key value pairs or do you just want to save all inputs into an array ?

Comment: I want to put the inputs into an array so I can push it onto an object, then I plant to add it to a .csv file(I know how to do that). Just can't figure out how to convert their inputs into an array, and then split it with semi-colons.

Comment: By inputs do you mean, the four values of firstname,lastname,age and email for a single user or these four values for multiple user inputs ?

Comment: You don't need to add the input variables to an array, you can directly pass them as arguments to the function newPeople() and then inside the function you can add those parameters into an object. Check the code in my fiddle.

Comment: I have a problem where it keeps coming up with "unexpected end of input" If there is anyway I can share my whole code with you I think it would be easier for you to help me, if that's not too much to ask.

Comment: The unexpected end of input error must probably be due to a syntax error (missing parentheses etc...)

Comment: for some reason it still doesn't add the array to my object when I try to push it onto it.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle and share your complete code there.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4wn8an44/3/ I hope I linked it right (btw I am using Sublime text 3 to write this, and if you need to csv file I can somehow give it to you).

Comment: get back to as soon as you can